# Join on UUID column not using index for multiple values

Tags: postgresql, uuid, query-planner

I have a PostgreSQL database that I cloned.

- Database 1 has `varchar(36)` as primary keys
- Database 2 (the clone) has `UUID` as primary keys.

Both contain the same data. What I don't understand is why queries on Database 1 will use the index but Database 2 will not. Here's the query:

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
select * from table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
where table1.id in (
'541edffc-7179-42db-8c99-727be8c9ffec',
'eaac06d3-e44e-4e4a-8e11-1cdc6e562996'
);
```

Database 1

```
Nested Loop  (cost=16.13..7234.96 rows=14 width=803) (actual time=0.072..0.112 rows=8 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=23
  ->  Index Scan using table1_pk on table1  (cost=0.56..17.15 rows=2 width=540) (actual time=0.042..0.054 rows=2 loops=1)
"        Index Cond: ((id)::text = ANY ('{541edffc-7179-42db-8c99-727be8c9ffec,eaac06d3-e44e-4e4a-8e11-1cdc6e562996}'::text[]))"
        Buffers: shared hit=12
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table2  (cost=15.57..3599.86 rows=904 width=263) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=4 loops=2)
        Recheck Cond: ((table1_id)::text = (table1.id)::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=3
        Buffers: shared hit=11
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table2_table1_id_fk  (cost=0.00..15.34 rows=904 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=4 loops=2)
              Index Cond: ((table1_id)::text = (table1.id)::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=8
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=416
Planning Time: 1.869 ms
Execution Time: 0.330 ms
```

Database 2

```
Gather  (cost=1000.57..1801008.91 rows=14 width=740) (actual time=11.580..42863.893 rows=8 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=863 read=631539 dirtied=631979 written=2523
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..1800007.51 rows=6 width=740) (actual time=28573.119..42856.696 rows=3 loops=3)
        Buffers: shared hit=863 read=631539 dirtied=631979 written=2523
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..678896.46 rows=1 width=519) (actual time=28573.112..42855.524 rows=1 loops=3)
"              Filter: (id = ANY ('{541edffc-7179-42db-8c99-727be8c9ffec,eaac06d3-e44e-4e4a-8e11-1cdc6e562996}'::uuid[]))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2976413
              Buffers: shared hit=854 read=631536 dirtied=631979 written=2523
        ->  Index Scan using table2_table1_id_fk on table2  (cost=0.56..1117908.70 rows=320236 width=221) (actual time=1.736..1.745 rows=4 loops=2)
              Index Cond: (table1_id = table1.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=9 read=3
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=376 read=15
Planning Time: 43.594 ms
Execution Time: 42864.044 ms
```

Some notes:

- The query is orders of magnitude faster in Database 1
- Having only one ID in the `WHERE` clause activates the index in both databases
- Casting to `::uuid` has no impact

I understand that these results are because the query planner calculates that the cost of the index in the `UUID` (Database 2) case is too high. But I'm trying to understand *why* it thinks that and if there's something I can do.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: The only conclusion that can be drawn from those execution plans is that an index scan on `id` cannot be used in database 2. Perhaps you forgot to add the primary key after all. Another reason could be that the index is extremely bloated: Does a `REINDEX` fix the problem?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the follow-up. Doing a `REINDEX DATABASE ...` didn't work. Your point about "the index being bloated" could be extremely valid: there's several million records here.